# Telling when an eigenvalue has a multiplicity of one or more

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$  Find all eigenvalues of A.

Solution: $A=\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&2&3\\1&2-\lambda&3\\1&2&3-\lambda\end{vmatrix}$

$A=\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&2&3\\1&2-\lambda&3\\0&\lambda&\lambda\end{vmatrix}$

$A=\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&2&3\\ \lambda&-\lambda&0 \\0&\lambda&\lambda\end{vmatrix}$

$A=\lambda^2\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&2&3\\ 1&-1 &0 \\0&1&-1\end{vmatrix}$

$0 = \lambda^2(6−\lambda)$

The eigenvalues are $0$, $0$ and $6$.

---

However, in the matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&1\\0&1-\lambda\end{vmatrix}$

$(1-\lambda)^2=0$

There is only one eigenvalue and it's $1$. How would you be able to tell when an eigenvalue is supposed to have a multiplicity of $1$ or more?

Comment: For the same reason you say the first matrix has eigenvalues $0,0,6$, the second one has eigenvalues $1,1$.

Comment: Do you mean *algebraic* or *geometric* multiplicity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) we can determine the multiplicity of an eigenvalue by looking at the by seeing if the term is squared, cubed, etc.

For example in the first example provided the characteristic polynomial was: $$\lambda^2(6-\lambda)$$

From the $\lambda^2$ in the beginning we know that  an there are two eigenvalues of $\lambda=0$. We know this because of the power the term is raised to.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to write the matrix as an outer product, namely $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\end{bmatrix}=ab^T.$$

For the first eigenvalue, let $v$ be a vector orthogonal to $b$ i.e. in the orthogonal complement of $b$. Then $Av=ab^Tv=a(0)=0v$ so $v$ is a right-eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, and since the orthogonal complement is 2D for $b\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we conclude that the (geometric!) multiplicity is 2. For the other eigenvalue, note that $Aa=ab^Ta=a(6)$ so $a$ is a right-eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda=6$.

PS: It is important that $a$ is not orthogonal to $b$. If it were, then $a$ would already lie in the orthogonal complement and would not yield a distinct eigenvector. So the geometric multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue would still be 2 and we wouldn't have another eigenvalue of multiplicity one.

Comment: To compare this answer with @PloniAlmoni's, note that the geometric multiplicities can't exceed the algebraic multiplicities. So the algebraic multiplicities must at least sum to 1+2=3, and since this is as large as possible we conclude that these are also 1,2.